# How Report Apparent Bug to an Apache Project?

Tags: apache, apache-poi, rstudio

Working with RStudio v1.1.456 on an iMac with macOS Mojave (v10.14) and encountered this error:

```
Loading required package: XLConnect
Loading required package: XLConnectJars
XLConnect 0.2-15 by Mirai Solutions GmbH [aut],
  Martin Studer [cre],
  The Apache Software Foundation [ctb, cph] (Apache POI),
  Graph Builder [ctb, cph] (Curvesapi Java library)
http://www.mirai-solutions.com
https://github.com/miraisolutions/xlconnect
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipSecureFile$1 (file:/Users/User/Library/R/3.5/library/XLConnect/java/poi-ooxml-3.17.jar) to field java.io.FilterInputStream.in
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipSecureFile$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

Because the message includes the request to "Please consider reporting this...", I attempted to do so—however, I've never filed a bug report with Apache, and an unclear as to how to make such a post.

Suggestions?

BIG THANKS!

Comment: What version of Apache POI are you using? And if not the latest, what happens when you upgrade?

Comment: This is likely to be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50071996/an-illegal-reflective-access-operation-has-occurred-apache-poi - Apache POI 4.0.0 removes the code in ZipSecureFile that was using Java Reflection.

Comment: There appears to have been a similar question asked on this forum: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51719176/r-xlconnect-loadworkbook-warnings-an-illegal-reflective-access-operation-has The suggestion in that answer was to install a different form of Java.